# How to generate Multiple File names in runtime in HADOOP?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have some data in csv format.

eg K1,K2,data1,data2,data3

here my mapper passes the key to reducer as K1K2
                       & Value as data1,data2,data3

I wanted to save this data in Multiple Files with file name being K1k2(or the key which reducer gets). Now If I'm using MultipleOutputs class, I have to mention the file names before mapper begins. But here , since only after reading the data from mapper, I can determine the key. How should i proceed?

PS I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate file names and pass them to MultipleOutputs in the Reducer like this:

```
public void setup(Context context) {
   out = new MultipleOutputs(context);
   ...
}

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable values, Context context) throws IOException,           InterruptedException {
  for (Text t : values) {
    out.write(key, t, generateFileName(<parameter list...>));
    // generateFileName is your function
  }
}

protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  out.close();
}
```

For more details read MultipleOutputs class reference: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html

Comment: No but it gives an error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Named output 'K1K2' not defined
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.checkNamedOutputName(MultipleOutputs.java:193)

Comment: If I add MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, FileName1.toString(), TextOutputFormat.class,NullWritable.class,Text.class); in generateOutput() method, how do i get the job in reducer. I have just started this might be a very basic question ?

Comment: you get the exception bcoz you have to define the MultipleOutputs in your 'driver' that runs the job.

Answer (score -2):

No need to predefine the output file names .Here you can use `MultipleOutputs` like this.

```
public class YourReducer extends Reducer<Text, Value, Text, Value> {
private Value result = null;
private MultipleOutputs<Text,Value> out;

 public void setup(Context context) {
   out = new MultipleOutputs<Text,Value>(context);    
 }
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Value> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // do your code
    out.write(key, result,"outputpath/"+key.getText());                
}
public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
    out.close();        
 }
```

}

Here it gives output in the following paths as

```
outputpath/K1
          /K2
          /K3
 .......
```

For this you should use `LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass()` instead of `FileOutputFormat`. Also need to add job configuration as `job.setOutputFormatClass(NullOutputFormat.class)` . But dont forget to give input and out paths using `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath()` and `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath()` as before. Then the generated files will be relative to the specified outputpath

Comment: ...and you have to define the MultipleOutputs in your 'driver' that runs the job. correct?

Comment: what you mean by defining multipleoutputs and driver?

Comment: the file that runs the job, you have to call  MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, ..., TextOutputFormat.class,...)